# IntelliJ IDEA "SpringIO" project reports "unable to make the module..."

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, spring-webflux

I have been using IntelliJ IDEA for Spring Webflux projects, without any issues. Now (using Ultimate 2019.2.1), build/rebuild reports successful completion, but issues warnings that modules are not able to be created and the Gradle project needs to be re-imported.

*"Unable to make the module Xxx, related gradle configuration was not found. Please re-import the Gradle project and try again."*

I have re-imported the project from the Gradle view, but this does not resolve the warning (i.e., same warning generated by build process).

I have also tried "*Invalidate and Restart*" to try clearing caches, again without resolving the warnings.

As a "hail Mary", I have uninstalled-and-reinstalled IntelliJ...again without resolving the warnings.

The project was generated as a "SpringIO" within the IDE, and the only dependency identified during generation was on Spring Webflux.

I have attempted to resolve this through JetBrains support (who have been helpful), but JetBrains seems unable to replicate the warnings.

This is the only source file in the project (i.e., the default "main")...

```
package foo.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is the *build.gradle* being used (although I had not seen the "dependency management" plugin in prior *build.gradle* files).

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'foo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
```

Comment: Did you try to [delete IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) to start with all the defaults? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may be needed to investigate it further. Also check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors.

Comment: Yes, I deleted all folders related to IntelliJ (including any that were empty, or were stored under user profiles). I also created the project, vice importing an existing project, to avoid as many sources of "prior bad behavior". As far as "minimal and complete", I've done my best with what's posted. If you create a project in IDEA using "Spring Initializer", Gradle, and Web->Reactive Web, the files shown are what should be generated that are unique to the build. I will, however, also check out the log. - Grazi

Comment: Zip and share the project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that JetBrains latest release (2019.2.1) has one-or-more issues, one of which seems to be the cause for the described behavior. I say "one-or-more issues" because I also discovered that "logging.level" entries in the application.properties file were not being honored by SLF4J/logback.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221673